# OpenMP accumulate array inside nested parallelism

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am converting an existing application to work with multiple threads and using OpenMP with nested parallelism for this purpose.

The code looks like this (Fortran)

```
!$omp parallel do private(array) ...
DO i=1...
...
C    ---- plenty of code ----
...
!$omp parallel do private(z1,z2,z3,value)...
    DO j=1...
        ...
!$omp critical
        DO z1=..
            DO z2=..
                DO z3=..
                    ...
                    value = ...
                    array(z1,z2,z3) = array(z1,z2,z3) + value
                END DO
            END DO
        END DO
!$omp end critical
    END DO
END DO
```

I added an OMP CRITICAL because the accumulation was not thread safe, but this is causing threads from other teams to wait unnecessarily.

What is the best way to parallelize this? Is there any way to make a reduction work in this case?

Comment: Investigate the topic of *OpenMP reductions*.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use nested parallelism in openMP? I never heard of it and would think it's rarely useful. How is the speedup with the simplest possible parallelization?

Comment: @JonatanÖström I think you're right. Here it looks as if what is wanted is "collapse(2)" on the outer loop, though even that may be unnecessary.(Or that may be impossible since there might be elided in the outer loop before the start of the inner one). Nested parallelism is generally a bad idea which leads to over-subscription.

Comment: Neither the first loop nor the second one can saturate the number of cores that is available on the CPU. By making both parallel, I am able to better take advantage of the available computing power. Let me edit my question for better clarification.